# A question about how RS latches work and the time an input needs to stay high after it has been supplied!

Tags: flipflop, latch

I have a RS latch constructed of 2 NOR gates, without enable input.

[image]

Lets say that the in the beginning the output is set to Q=1, Q'=0. (pic1)

In a given moment R is pulsed high, and Q is calculated as (R+Q')'=(1+0)'=0. (pic2)

[image]

So now Q supplies 0 instead of one to the other NOR gate.

[image]

Now Q' is calculated as (0+0)'=1.(pci4)

[image]

Now as i can see from the picture while the propagation of the signal from the first NOR to the second, and then back from the second to the first lasted, the pulse at R stayed high. Therefore in this moment both signals to the first NOR gate are high. Q is again calculated as (1+1)'=0, so it doesn't change.

The moment comes when R becomes 0 again and Q is calculated again, Q=(0+1)'=0, but still doesn't change.(pic 5)

[image]

At this moment both inputs are low and the latch is in a stable reset state.

The pictures are from an animation, but all of this wasn't clear to me until i separated the animation. This might not have been that much of a question but a discussion, because i need someones confirmation if i'm right. Does this mean that the input has to stay high for at least the time needed for the first NOR gate to be calculated, the new pulse supplied to the second gate, and that pulse supplied back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, to make a long story short, the input needs to remain stable until the positive feedback has finished propagating from the gate outputs to the gate inputs.

If you violate the minimum pulse width the latch may simply ignore the pulse, it may oscillate, or it may become metastable.

Comment: This is known as "hold time".

Comment: No, hold time is a specification for a data input with respect to a clock. For an RS latch the specification is minimum pulse width.

Comment: For more information about "asynchronous systems", this can help https://www.ee.ucl.ac.uk/~ademosth/E757/Topic6.pdf